# Popping an empty linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So my goal is to remove a linked list head node. But I am having trouble doing that when I have an empty list here is what I have so far

```
conscell *ll_pop(conscell *list)
{
    if ( list == NULL) {            // do nothing
        return list;
    }
    if ( list != NULL) {
        conscell *p = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = p;
        return list;
    }
```

Here is the implementation. We do a series of pops. First we pop two nodes then we pop 3 nodes

```
 conscell *ll_push(conscell *list, void *data)
{
    conscell *new = xmalloc(sizeof *new);   // allocate associate memory
    new->data = data;           // assign data
    new->next = list;           // attach the new node to the old list
    return new;
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you facing???

Comment: so i created a test file with  4 nodes and i popped it 5 times but its gives me message segmentation fault @avinashpandey

Comment: are you ensuring next is NULL for the last item?

Comment: in fact, let's see your push

Comment: Yes please show the push code along with the main function from where you are calling this..

Comment: sorry about that here it is @KeithNicholas

Comment: It seems like there is no problem. let's see your `xmalloc`.

Comment: I also see no problem. Please show the calling code.

Comment: The push routine is incomplete. Do you remember to update the list head pointer after pushing? I mean do you do something like `conscell *new_head = ll_push(list, some_data); list = new_head;` ...? And similary for pop.

Answer (score 2):

How are you defining an empty list? Set the list to `NULL` in main before calling the function, and it should work.

Comment: This is how  I am define an empty list conscell *list = NULL; 
So i created a test file with 4 nodes and i popped it 5 times but its gives me message segmentation fault @user3711622

Comment: If the whole list is `NULL` it shouldn't have any nodes.

Comment: @TimothyBrown If the list starts as `NULL` than the problem doesn't seem to be in any of those functions but probably in how you are using them. Show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use the return value of the pop to modify the list pointer.

Your main should look something like this.

```
int main(void)
{
    conscell *list= NULL;

    ....

    list = ll_push(list,data1);
    list = ll_push(list,data2);
    list = ll_push(list,data3);
    list = ll_push(list,data4);

    list = ll_pop(list);
    list = ll_pop(list);        
    list = ll_pop(list);
    list = ll_pop(list);
    list = ll_pop(list);

}
```

The 4th pop will assign the list pointer back to NULL and the fifth and further pops will just return normally.